# Stop trying to Download block maps in electron-builder update

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I'm looking for a way to disable looking for the blockmap file in the update process in Electron-builder. This will never exist for us and we're happy to rely on the full download. So far I cant seem to find any way to do this. but it results in the log being spammed with the fail and a stack trace. If this is not possible is there a way to explicitly declare a URL for the blockmap in the latest.yml rather than it just insert .blockmap in the exe url. As i'm hoping a 404 wont result in the stack trace, as we are getting with the 403. Thanks